# how to change the text in the textview depending on the percentage the Seekbar in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-seekbar

I want to change the text in depending on the seekbar, my max seekbar is up to 16.
if i had a

- progress = <2 had a text "Hello"

if

- progress> 2, but 5 < progress "you should be better!"

, etc.

but it's doesn't worked , i don't' know what to do

Thank u advance all of you!!

**Code**
this is XML TextView

```
 <com.example.garage.view.WriterTextView
        android:id="@+id/texview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font_friends"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:text="@string/old_you"
        android:textColor="@color/dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.124" />


<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:max="16"
        android:min="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guide1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guide1"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/bg_seekbar"
        android:thumbOffset="10dp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/ic_ellipse"/>
```

**Class Extension**

```
fun startCoroutinesTimer(
        delayMillis: Long,
        repeatCount: Long,
        scope: CoroutineScope,
        action: () -> Unit
){}

fun SeekBar.setSeekbarChangeListener(action: (Int) -> Unit){ //progress от 0 -100
    setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, progress: Int, p2: Boolean) {
            action(progress)
            /*textage.setText(progress)*/
            if (textage != null){

                textview.setText(progress+"");
                if(progress >= 3 && progress < 4)
                    textview.text = context.getString(R.string.wfsf)
                else if(progress >= 4 && progress < 14)
                    textview.text = context.getString(R.string.ggdgr)
                else if(progress >= 15 && progress <= 17)
                    textview.text = context.getString(R.string.ggdfghj)
            }
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {}

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {}

    })
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Comment: @Tenfour04 nothing textview doesn’t showing text

Comment: Are you sure `textage` isn’t null? Use the debugger with breakpoints to see if the code you expect is even running.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you very much !!!! low bow to you from me!